# What is the status of std::ranges::split_view in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, c++23

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/split_view, `std::ranges::split_view` must be available since C++20. However the example on the same page contains "C++23" in its text:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>
 
int main() {
    constexpr std::string_view words{"Hello-_-C++-_-23-_-!"};
    constexpr std::string_view delim{"-_-"};
    for (const std::string_view word : std::ranges::split_view(words, delim)) {
        std::cout << std::quoted(word) << ' ';
    }
}
```

Both GCC and MSVC refuse to accept this example in C++20 mode. MSVC in particular prints:

```
The contents of <ranges> are available only in c++latest mode with concepts support;
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4fGGb3aqY

GCC starts accepting the code with `-std=c++2b` command-line switch (meaning forthcoming C++23), while MSVC even with `/std:c++latest` option reports the error

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::ranges::split_view<std::basic_string_view<char,std::char_traits<char>>,std::basic_string_view<char,std::char_traits<char>>>::_Outer_iter<true>::value_type' to 'std::basic_string_view<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6z48Mz45j

Is there something wrong with the example in C++20 mode, or it really requires some C++23 features from the compiler?

Comment: Don't write `ranges::split_view`, write `views::split`.

Comment: Don't be mislead with _The contents of <ranges> are available only in c++latest mode with concepts support;_, it does not mean that `<ranges>` is not c++20, it means that MSVC STL implementers decided to wait till `<ranges>` stabilize: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1814#issuecomment-845572895

Answer (score 9):

### Update:

As mentioned in the comments, [P2499](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2499r0.html) makes `string_view`'s range constructor `explicit` in C++23, so `subrange` is no longer implicitly convertible to `string_view` in the original example.

You need to explicitly construct `string_view` as [cppreference updated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/split_view):

```
for (const auto word : std::views::split(words, delim))
    // with string_view's C++23 range constructor:
    std::cout << std::quoted(std::string_view(word)) << ' ';
```

---

This

```
for (const std::string_view word : std::ranges::split_view(words, delim)) {
    std::cout << std::quoted(word) << ' ';
}
```

requires one C++20 defect to be resolved and one C++23 feature to be implemented to be well-formed.

The first one is [P2210](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2210r2.html), which renamed the original `split_view` to `lazy_split_view` and redesigned the new `split_view`. One of the improvements is that its `value_type` is defined as `subrange`, which means that when the new `split_view` is applied to a `contiguous_range`, the splitting subranges will also be `contiguous_range`s.

So `split_view(words, delim)` in your example will return a range of `subrange` which models `contiguous_range`.

The second one is [P1989](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1989r2.pdf), which adds a range constructor to `string_view` so that it can accept a `contiguous_range` and initialize its members.

Since it is a C++23 feature, this is why the example contains "C++23" in its text.

Comment: I guess it's no longer a C++23 feature, since that `string_view` constructor is now `explicit` ([P2499](https://wg21.link/p2499)).

Comment: @Barry You're absolutely right, buddy. Done.

Comment: I like how many times this example has changed over the last 3 years.

Comment: @Barry Is there any technical reason why `split_view` can not be a bidirectional range given that `chunk_by_view` could be?

Comment: Yeah - chunk_by's predicate is applied to consecutive elements, you can do that backwards. split matches a range - which can give different behavior forwards and backwards.